# reassign value to val in scala.collection.immutable.List

Tags: list, scala

I am newbie to scala. When click to read source code of a method of List, Intellij IDEA gave messages of reassign value to val. In `readObject` method, there is a line:

```
current.tl = Nil
```

where t1 is val

So why this line is allowed there ?

Comment: You need to please explain the question. What is gettign re-assigned and where? What is `readObject`?

Comment: Current might be a val instead of t1. Just a guess.

Comment: @Jatin the `t1` in `current.t1 = Nil` is reassigned. `t1` is a val in `final case class ::[B]` of package scala.collection.immutable. `readObject` is a private method defined from line number 361 in scala.collection.immutable.List. Scala version is 2.10.x

Comment: Why do you think that the `current.tl` is of type `val` and not `var`? The declaration of the class `final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B]` seems to prove otherwise. Not sure why the error is shown in IntelliJ though, I've tried to use similar constructs in my code and have seen no errors.

Comment: @Norbert Radyk Just found that `t1` is a var in scala's source code github, while in IntelliJ pressing control and click on `t1` will show `t1` is val `final case class ::[B](private val hd : B, private[scala] val tl : scala.collection.immutable.List[B])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That in `scala.collection.immutable.List`:

```
final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
```

`private[scala] var tl: List[B]` - **var** modifier before **tl** and that why **tl** can be modified.

Comment: It still doesn't explain though why IntelliJ is showing 'reassignment to val' error in the lines 368 and 372. IDE issue?